# mediaplayer onErrorListener doesn't catch errors

Tags: android, media-player

I am developing an app that plays http audio stream and I have to check an audio stream whether it works correctly. The problem is that I have found the way how to do it but it takes too much time, I have tried to decrease the time but with no result. I think that mediaplayer retries to connect to "dead" stream for 10 times before it stops, so the problem is how can I manually stop this reconnections after first failure, cause errorListener doesn't catch this error.

```
08-28 08:58:41.211 1335-12727/? E/NuCachedSource2: source returned error -1, 10 retries left
```

Here is my code:

```
 class CheckTask extends AsyncTask<RadioStation, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected  Boolean doInBackground(final RadioStation... radioStation){




        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {

            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(radioStation[0].mUrl);

            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            System.out.println(radioStation[0].mName + "prepare Async");
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    System.out.println(radioStation[0].mName + " OK");
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
            });

            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    System.out.println(radioStation[0].mName + " Error");

                    return true;
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception radio check " + e);
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }










        return true;

    }



    @Override
    protected  void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean){
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling  `mediaPlayer.release();` on `onPrepared` ?. It should be `mediaPlayer.start()`. And since you are releasing the Mediplayer `onErrorListner` wouldn't be called.

Comment: I only need to know if stream works, it catches errors, but how to catch source returned error - thats the question.

Comment: I just answered that. Can you please replace mediaPlayer.release() with mediaPlayer.start() on mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListeners onPrepared?.And check if the same error occurs.

Comment: I still didn't understood what your issue is. onError was not triggered probably because no error was thrown or there was an error even before you set the listener and was caught  by 'try catch' .  If you are looking for what are the errors that can occur then this is the list https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html#onError(android.media.MediaPlayer,int,int)